# Can't create an array of type const char*

Tags: array, data-type

I have something being returned as a const char* and would like to save it to an array.

I've tried this:

```
const char* book[amtBooks] = "";
```

and get this error:

```
error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
```

Comment: How about with `const char* book[amtBooks] = { NULL };`. This will initialize every book to a null pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `const char* book[amtBooks]` is an array of pointers.
- `""` is an array of chars (with only a NUL character).

You can initialize an array of chars with an array of chars:

```c++
const char foo[] = "hello";
```

You can also initialize a pointer to char with an array of chars:

```c++
const char *bar = "good bye";
```

this works because of the “decay to pointer” feature of C and C++.

But initializing an array of pointers with an array of chars simply does
not make sense. An array of pointers to char could be initialized as

```c++
const char *book[] = {"hello", "good bye"};
```